# Prove that: $\frac{(\sec\theta-\tan\theta)^2+1}{\sin\theta-\tan\theta}=2\sec\theta$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

> Prove that:$$\frac{(\sec\theta-\tan\theta)^2+1}{\sin\theta-\tan\theta}=2\sec\theta$$

So, I've tried solving this for a full day and have only been frustrated. Kindly help me out and maintain my sanity. And kindly stray to using basic trigonometric identities and ratios not double angle or anything like that.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Math SE. To solve problems like this, write everything in terms of $c:=\cos\theta,\,s:=\sin\theta$ using $\tan\theta=s/c$ etc., then repeatedly use $c^2+s^2=1$.

Comment: In future, [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) will make it easier to understand what equation you're writing.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! ... Please double-check the formatting of the equation. As written, the identity is invalid: substituting $\theta=0$ makes the right-hand side $2$ and the left-hand side *undefined*. ... Also, if you've spent a day working on this, please tell us what you've tried and where you got stuck. This will help people avoid wasting time duplicating your effort or explaining things you already understand. ... Good luck!

Comment: I agree with @Blue. I think the $\sin$ should be $\sec$. Note that $1/(\sec\theta-\tan\theta)=\sec\theta+\tan\theta$.

Comment: @J.G.: Yes, the identity becomes valid by changing the $\sin$ to $\sec$. Good catch!

Comment: Suppose $\theta$ is in the first quadrant.  Then on the LHS the numerator is positive, the denominator is negative and the RHS is positive.  This poses a contradiction, and the proposition is not true.

Answer (score 2):

The equation is false because when $\theta=\dfrac{\pi}{3}$, then LHS=$-\dfrac{16}{\sqrt 3}+8$ and RHS=$4.$

---

As commented to your question, the equation should be
$$\frac{(\sec\theta-\tan\theta)^2+1}{\sec\theta-\tan\theta}=2\sec\theta.$$

Using $\sec \theta=\dfrac{1}{\cos \theta}$ and $1+\tan^2\theta=\dfrac{1}{\cos^2\theta}$, you can see the denominator of LHS is $\dfrac{2}{1+\sin\theta}$ and the numerator of LHS is $\dfrac{1-\sin\theta}{\cos\theta}.$

Thus $$\frac{(\sec\theta-\tan\theta)^2+1}{\sec\theta-\tan\theta}=\dfrac{2}{1+\sin\theta}\dfrac{\cos\theta}{1-\sin\theta}.$$ You can show this is equal to $2\sec \theta.$